# add additional partition after increasing OS disk size

Tags: centos, redhat, fdisk, parted

As part of add additional partition – sda3 we extend the OS disk from 50g to 120g from the vsphere client ( VM Linux server )

And we perform rescan , instead of reboot

```
lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  120G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0  119G  0 part
  ├─Vlpr-lvm_root 253:0    0   10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─Vlpr-lvm_swap 253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─Vlpr-lvm_var  253:2    0  10G  0 lvm  /var


fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p0
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
No free sectors available

Command (m for help):
```

As we can see above we have the partitions – sda1 sda2  , but when we select the partition number – 3 from fdisk then its complain about - `No free sectors available`
In spite we are not use sda3

Any suggestions why fdisk give the error - `No free sectors available`

I just to mention that we prefer to not do a reboot if this is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a third partition because you have already resized the second partition to use the newly allocated space. Now you need to go on to the next steps, resizing the PV, resizing the LV, and finally resizing the filesystem.

Resize the PV:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

Resize the LV:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/Vlpr-lvm_root
```

Finally resize the filesystem. (You did not give the filesystem type but you can easily look up this command.)

Comment: about - resizing the PV, resizing the LV, and finally resizing the filesystem , can you please add the instructions about how to do it? in your post

Comment: maybe I am not explain my self , we need to add additional partition  , and create on this partition new file system

Comment: @sheffadmin You DO NOT need a new partition. I added the commands you need to the answer. I did not include them originally because I thought you already had them in the tutorial you were following.

Comment: about the resize the FS I get --> resize2fs /dev/sda2
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: @sheffadmin Your filesystem isn't on `/dev/sda2`! Use the correct device `/dev/mapper/Vlpr-lvm_root`

Comment: but anyway this is the solution that I searched - https://serverfault.com/questions/1042636/how-to-increase-the-free-space-in-a-volume-group-in-lvm-after-expend-vm-disk-siz